# jQuery: using $(this) inside a callback function of a self-defined jQuery function

Tags: jquery, callback

This is the self-defined jQuery function

```
$.fn.wider = function(callback) {  
    $(this).animate({width: 500}, function() {
        callback();
    });
};
```

Call the function

```
$('#div').wider(function() {
    console.log('div resizing done');

    // $(this) refers to window instead of $('#div')
    $(this).css({background: '#f00'});
});
```

so how can I use $(this) like in the click funciton below?

```
$('#div').click(function() {
    console.log('div clicked');

    // $(this) refers to $('#div')
    $(this).css({background: '#f00'});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply).

```
$.fn.wider = function(callback) {  
    $(this).animate({width: 500}, function() {
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback.apply(this); // <- here
        }
    });
};
```

A slightly more general implementation:

```
$.fn.wider = function(callback) {
    var self = this;
    $(this).animate({width: 500}, function() {
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback.apply(self);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Or [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/call) :-P

Comment: Thanks Matt, that works. I still got so much to learn in jQuery... :(

Comment: @pepsi that's JavaScript, not (just) jQuery.